# WCF unable to separate/encapsulate dataContracts into own cs files - Stack Overflow Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have an interesting problem. Whenever I try and separate Data Contracts into their own cs files...I get process is terminated due to stack overflow exception when using one of these data contracts within a service method. Seems that I need to put the data contracts within the interface class for the issue to be resolved however, I want to have a separate cs file for each data contract under a DTO directory within my wcf service application. No problem with the code, the error occurs only when i try and move Data Contracts into their own classes. Some insight would be nice onto why this is occurring. The wcf test client will generate the correct response when using the methods but when hooked up to my console app. Only data contracts within the interface cs file(Iservice.cs) works with methods but, data contracts in their own cs file throws the exception.

Data Contract in its own cs file.

```
using developer1.Core.Dto.Account;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace developer1.Core.Dto.Account
{
    [DataContract]
    public class AccountDto
    {
        Guid accountId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Guid userId = Guid.NewGuid();
        string accountName = "default";
        string bankName = "default";


        [DataMember]
        public Guid AccountId
        {
            get { return accountId; }
            set { accountId = value; }
        }


        [DataMember]
        public Guid UserId
        {
            get { return userId; }
            set { userId = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string AccountName
        {
            get { return accountName; }
            set { accountName = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string BankName
        {
            get { return bankName; }
            set { bankName = value; }
        }



    }
}
```

Method consuming object.

```
public AccountDto createAccount(string accountName, string bankName)
{
    AccountDto newAccount = new AccountDto() { AccountName = accountName, BankName = bankName };
    return newAccount;
}
```

Iservice class

```
using developer1.Core.Dto.Account;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
//using AccountDto = developer1.Core.Dto.Account.AccountDto;

namespace developer1.Core.ServiceContracts
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType createComposite(string value);

        [OperationContract]
        List<AccountDto> GenerateMultipleAccounts(int count);
        // TODO: Add your service operations here
        [OperationContract]
        AccountDto createAccount(string accountName, string bankName);

        [OperationContract]
        AccountDto2 createAccount2(string stringValue, bool boolValue);
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }

    public class AccountDto2
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }


    }


}
```

Once again any data contracts within the interface class will cause the methods to work properly. But any contracts in their own cs files breaks the methods with a stack overflow exception

Comment: So I have solved this dreaded issue. You must create a WCF Service Library instead of a WCF Service Application. My god that is stupid that the application wont let you split your components outside of the interface.